# Error al intentar obtener el valor de un objeto con toRef

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Estoy realizando el consumo de una api realizada en Go y por medio de Vue 3, la obtención de datos lo hace de forma correcta, entonces los datos que obtengo los ingreso en un método reactive para poder trabajar con objetos y los envio a otro componente por medio de props, es en ese momento donde me genera un error el cual no he podido solucionar y es que cuando obtengo los props lo paso por toRef para no perder la reactividad, y la informacion funciona sin problemas, el problema empieza a suceder es cuando actualizo la pagina pues la informacion que tengo se pierda pero solo cuando intento obtener el value de toRef:
Este es mi componente que obtiene los datos de la api:

```
export default {
  components: { EditProject },
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute();
    const project = reactive({});

    onMounted(() => {
      nextTick(() => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/projects/${route.params.id}`)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .catch((error) => console.error(error))
          .then((data) => {
            Object.assign(project, data);
          });
      });
    });

    return {
      project,
    };
  },
};
```

Y este es el metodo que obtiene ese objeto por medio de props:

```
export default {
  props: {
    project: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const content = toRef(props, 'project');

    const name = toRef(content.value, 'name');
    const description = toRef(content.value, 'description');
    const endProject = toRef(content.value, 'endProject');
    const user = toRef(content.value, 'user');
    const users = ref();

    ...

    return {
      name,
      description,
      endProject,
      user,
      users,
      editProject,
    };
  },
```

Este es el código de muestra para mostrar por consola los datos:

```
const end_date = toRefs(props.project, 'end_date');
console.log(end_date);
```

Lo que me muestra por consola es lo siguiente:

```
created_at: ObjectRefImpl {_object: Proxy, _key: "created_at", __v_isRef: true}
description: ObjectRefImpl {_object: Proxy, _key: "description", __v_isRef: true}
end_date: ObjectRefImpl
__v_isRef: true
_key: "end_date"
_object: Proxy {id_project: 3, name: "gbhnju", description: "derftgyh", start_date: "2021-08-06T00:00:00Z", end_date: "2021-08-17T00:00:00Z", …}
value: "2021-08-17T00:00:00Z"
[[Prototype]]: Object
id_project: ObjectRefImpl {_object: Proxy, _key: "id_project", __v_isRef: true}
name: ObjectRefImpl {_object: Proxy, _key: "name", __v_isRef: true}
progress: ObjectRefImpl {_object: Proxy, _key: "progress", __v_isRef: true}
project_state: ObjectRefImpl {_object: Proxy, _key: "project_state", __v_isRef: true}
start_date: ObjectRefImpl {_object: Proxy, _key: "start_date", __v_isRef: true}
updated_at: ObjectRefImpl {_object: Proxy, _key: "updated_at", __v_isRef: true}
user: ObjectRefImpl {_object: Proxy, _key: "user", __v_isRef: true}
user_creation: ObjectRefImpl {_object: Proxy, _key: "user_creation", __v_isRef: true}
```

Pero cuando quiero mostrar por consola el value del toRef me genera un undefined, o si actualizo la pagina el obtejo es como si se perdiera:

```
console.log(end_date.value);
```

Este es lo que me muestra cuando actualizo la pagina:

```
[[Prototype]]: Object
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

Comment: Puedes compartir el error que te sale?

Comment: @BrayanMartínezSantana intente ser lo mas especifico en el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Flujo del problema

- `0s` El componente padre hace una llamada a tu api (digamos que tarda 1seg)
- `0.1s` El componente padre le pasa `project` (es `{}` a este punto) al componente hijo.
- `0.2s` El componente hijo recibe a `project` con valor `{}` y guarda en `name` el valor de `toRef(content.value, 'name')` pero `project.name` es `undefined`, así que se crea una referencia a ello.
- `0.3s` El componente hijo muestra `undefined` en el `template`
- `1s` El componente padre termina la llamada, actualiza `project` y se manda la información al componente hijo pero el hijo solo actualiza `prop.project` pero no a `name` (pues en `0.2s` ni existía el atributo).
- Tu componente hijo sigue diciendo `undefined`.

### Solución

En el componente padre:

```
// En vez de hacer:
const project = reactive({});

// haz lo siguiente:
const project = reactive({
  name: "",
  user: {},
  // ...
});
```

En el componente hijo:

```
setup(props) {
  const { project } = toRefs(props);
  const {
    name,
    user,
    // ...
  } = toRefs(project.value);
  
  // usas tus variables en lo que necesites ...
  
  return { name, user };
}
```

No es la única solución y puedes usar `computed` o `watch` pero creo que sería más trabajo del necesario.

[image: Edit Usando una API en Vue]

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero es mismo problema persiste, además de ingresar dato por dato no seria mejor utilizar ref en vez de reactive?

Comment: Pues `ref` manda a llamar a `reactive`, así que puedes seguir usándolo pero cambia un poco la forma en la que trabajas con objetos si usas [`ref`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61452458/ref-vs-reactive-in-vue-3).
No sé que más pueda estar mal, puedes compartir un gif, o un codesandox para que pueda mejorar. :C

Comment: disculpa probe mal tu respuesta ahora si la probe bien, funciona muy bien